# Debugging Smart Card Minidriver

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, smartcard, cng, mscapi

I'm currently working on a CNG Smart Card minidriver.

To test some functionality I'd like to use `makecert` to import a Private Key into the Smart Card.

Unfortunately for every change I make I have to copy my `minidriver.dll` to the system32 directory. But once I called `makecert` for the first time, the minidriver.dll will be in use, and I can't overwrite it unless I reboot my PC (which honestly takes too much time..)

Is there way to overwrite it without rebooting?

My second attempt would be to debug it using Visual Studio and starting `makecert` from Visual Studio. But I will be prompted with: **The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.**

Is there a way to debug the minidriver.dll within Visual Studio using `makecert.exe`?

Thanks for your help.